# Is there a better way to merge two dicts of sets?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am using this code to merge one dict into another - if a key exists, it should merge the values from both dicts:

```
source_dict = defaultdict(set)
target_dict = defaultdict(set)

def merge_dict(source_dict, target_dict):
    for source_key in source_dict:
        if source_key in target_dict:
            target_dict[source_key].update(source_dict[source_key])
        else:
            target_dict[source_key] = source_dict[source_key]
```

Is there a way to optimize the `merge_dict` function above? For example, to make it more concise or more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [`defaultdict`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). So you don't need the `if/else`... Just do:

```
def merge_dict(source_dict, target_dict):
    for source_key, source_value in source_dict.items():
        target_dict[source_key].update(source_value)
```

If the `source_key` is not in `target_dict`, an empty set will be created and immediately `update`d. That's exactly the use-case for `defaultdict`s...

Answer (score 3):

You could wirte it as an update from a comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict

source_dict = defaultdict(set,{'a':{1,2,3},'b':{4,5,6}})
target_dict = defaultdict(set,{'b':{5,6,7},'c':{8,9}})

target_dict.update((k,s|target_dict[k]) for k,s in source_dict.items())

print(target_dict)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'b': {4, 5, 6, 7}, 'c': {8, 9}, 'a': {1, 2, 3}})
```